# How to show form after onclick event React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a React component which returns a form with a button. When I click the button, I want another different form to show up on the same page. How do I do that? How do I return next form when I click the button? Below is just an example to give the main idea

```
function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <button onclick={showForm}></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please describe more where you want to render form mean you want to toggel first form or create another div.

Comment: You should at least make an effort with some code.  Lacking that, I'll simply say put the next form into a modal and have the onclick function set the modal visibility to true.  Its easy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define an state to handle the visibility of your form.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const showForm = () => {
    setShowForm(!showForm);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <button onClick={showForm}></button>
      </form>

      {showForm && (
        <form>
          ...
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tertiary operators.
Here is a sample that you could use that changes from showing one component to another one.

Set state to be false initially then change it to true when the button is clicked this can be in your App.js then pass it down to the component that renders it.

```
const [ editing, setEditing ] = useState(false)

const editRow = user => {
        setEditing(true)

        setCurrentUser({ id: user.id, name: user.name, username: user.username })
    }
```

The button of the initial component should be like this

```
 <button onClick={() => setEditing(false)} className="button muted-button">
        Cancel
    </button>
<div/>
```

In your main App.js this is how you switch between the two components

```
<div>
    {editing ? : (render what component you want when it is set to true ) : (render the component you want when it is set to false)}
```