# How to make a form shown when a button is clicked using a functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

cause when I search this, I only see codes in a class components.
also, how to show the same form n times depending on how many times the user clicked the button?

thank you in advance

edit: here's my initial code which i copied from someone's answer in another question. the problem is that whenever I click the button, it would show me the hidden part but it would only show for a second then refreshes the page and it's back to default where it is not shown.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Test() {

  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const showForms = () => {
    setShowForm(!showForm);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <button onClick={showForms}>click me</button>
      </form>

      {showForm && (
        <form>
          <h1>hello</h1>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: if you can share what you have tried so far, we can help you out.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please share what you tried and if appropriate show some code. Otherwise, this question has been asked a couple of times. Please, refer to the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62240808/8369565

Comment: @G_S I edited my post to show my initial code and my problem with it.

Comment: @VictorKarangwa Yeah I used it as my reference but it doesn't work for me. I edited my post to indicate my problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Main = () => {
  const [showIt, setShowIt] = useState(true);
    return (
       <div>
          {showIt ?
          <div className={"visible"}></div>
          :
          <div className={"invisible"}></div>}
       <button onClick={()=> setShowIt(!showIt)}>change state</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: it works! my question is that the part where it has {"invisible"} className will really not show anything even if I try to put something on it?

edit: also, how do i make another form show depending on how many times the user clicks the button again?